# Behavior while registering specific assembly types as implemented interfaces

Tags: c#, autofac

Autofac testing.

1 interface named `IEchoRepo`, and its 2 implemented classes, `EchoRepo` and `TestEchoRepo`.

I'm just wondering why Autofac builder would select the non-test one (in case is `EchoRepo`) if I put builder in the following way:

```
builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies())
       .Where(t => t.IsAbstract == false && t.Name.EndsWith("Repo"))
       //.Except <EchoRepo>() <-- don't except any one
       .AsImplementedInterfaces()
       .InstancePerRequest();
```

==> Result: `EchoRepo`

It means if I need to exclude non-test class if I would like use my `TestEchoRepo`, like this:

```
// Test Mode
builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies())
       .Where(t => t.IsAbstract == false && t.Name.EndsWith("Repo"))
       .Except <EchoRepo>() // exclude what I don't want
       .AsImplementedInterfaces()
       .InstancePerRequest();
```

==> Result: `TestEchoRepo`

Another way, I can also config by this. However, it isn't what I'm asking about.

```
builder.RegisterType<TestEchoRepo>()
       .As<IEchoRepo>()
       .InstancePerRequest();
```

`IEchoRepo.cs` / `EchoRepo.cs` / `TestEchoRepo.cs`:

```
public interface IEchoRepo : IBaseRepository
{
    string Say();
}

public class EchoRepo : IEchoRepo
{
    public string Say()
    {
        return "EchoRepo";
    }
}

public class TestEchoRepo : IEchoRepo
{
    public string Say()
    {
        return "TestEchoRepo";
    }
}
```

Therefore, can I say that Autofac builder will choose implemented interfaces by some naming rules ??

Not really clear about it. Any hint would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check out [the source of `RegisterAssemblyTypes`](https://github.com/autofac/Autofac/blob/4c87e3c59ca1a6b087379218cada9f98549694b3/src/Autofac/Features/Scanning/ScanningRegistrationExtensions.cs) what you'll see is that types are retrieved via a LINQ query over the set of assemblies you pass in.

When you boil it down, in *pseudocode* it amounts to:

```
public void RegisterAssemblies(Assembly[] assemblies)
{
  foreach(var assembly in assemblies)
  {
    foreach(var type in assembly.GetTypes())
    {
      Register(type);
    }
  }
}
```

Again, that's not the actual code (obviously) but basically what it comes down to after exception handling, filtering out types that can't be loaded, filtering out types that can't be instantiated (delegates, interfaces), and so on.

**The order of registration, then, is influenced by the order in which you feed in the assemblies and the order in which the reflection API provides the list of types in each assembly.**

Basically, Autofac isn't "choosing" an order for your type registrations - .NET reflection is.

The way Autofac works in general is that when you register more than one of a service (`EchoRepo` and `TestEchoRepo`) that **last one in wins**. If you are getting the `TestEchoRepo` it's because in the list of assembly/type resolution, either you're providing the assembly with `EchoRepo` *first* or, if they're both in the same assembly, reflection is providing `EchoRepo` in the list of types *first*. `TestEchoRepo` is then getting registered later, so when you resolve one `IEchoRepo` what you get is the last one registered - `TestEchoRepo`.

If you need to control the order of types and registrations, it's recommended you manually register types rather than doing large-scale assembly scanning.

Comment: I've provide 2 different scenarios for test mode and development mode, such as t.IsClosedTypeof(typeof(IMock<>)  vs ! t.IsClosedTypeof(typeof(IMock<>). So no Autofac or .NET reflection ambiguous registering results from now on. Thanks for your explanation.

Comment: @Kevin you may have left this comment on the wrong answer. :)

Comment: I left this cus focusing on NOT ambiguous registering ways for example. Also, thanks for @Chui Tey's recommendation. :P

Answer (score 0):

While I'd caution against registering every type in all the assemblies - since you are effectively giving up a lot of control and expose yourself to a litany of runtime errors. Your problem can be solved using a marker interface or custom attributes.

```
public interface IMock { }

public class TestEchoRepo : IEchoRepo, IMock
{
    public string Say()
    {
        return "TestEchoRepo";
    }
}

// Test environment
builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies())
            .Where(t => t.IsAbstract == false && t.Name.EndsWith("Repo"))
            .Where(t => typeof(IMock).IsAssignableFrom(t))
            .AsImplementedInterfaces()
            .InstancePerRequest();
```

For more generality you might wish to do this:

```
public interface IMock<T> where T : class { } 

public class TestEchoRepo: IEchoRepo, IMock<IEchoRepo>
{
   ...
}

// Test environment
builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies())
            .Where(t => t.IsAbstract == false)
            .Where(t => t.IsClosedTypeof(typeof(IMock<>)))
            .AsImplementedInterfaces()
            .InstancePerRequest();
```

Comment: For WebApi implementation use, each controller binds with its repo shouldn't instanciated per request ? Though I agree it's less effective. And yes, I think check additional interface name like IMock as the test mode selector is a very intuitive design.

Comment: `InstancePerRequest` is fine. I was questioning the wisdom doing using `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()` since that would pick up a lot of types.

Comment: Roger that, thank you. However, return to the point, the behavior while found more ImplementedInterfaces, like EchoRepo and TestEchoRepo (all end with "Repo"), why EchoRepo injects to controller successfully instead of TestEchoRepo ?